# Javascript testing equivalent of Ruby's rspec let

Tags: javascript, testing

In the Ruby world, using rspec, we have a feature available to us called `let` (https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let).  Its primary benefit is that it's lazy evaluated, so we can write tests like this:

```
describe Thing do
  describe "#process" do
    let(:arg) { nil }
    let(:result) { Thing.new.process(arg) }

    context "given 3" do
      let(:arg) { 3 }

      it "returns 12" do
        expect(result).to eq 12
      end
    end

    context "given 7" do
      let(:arg) { 7 }

      it "returns 42" do
        expect(result).to eq 42
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The point being we don't have to have a line to calculate the `result` inside every single `it` block.

My question is: **In the world of Javascript, is there a library or framework which provides an equivalent feature?**

I am used to writing with Jasmine, but I'm not married to that, and could use Mocha or something else if it had this lazy evalution feature I'm looking for.

I suspect there's a way to do it with a long-winded convolution of `beforeEach` and `function () {...}` declarations and things like that, but ideally proposed solutions would have a nice, concise and elegant syntax.

I'm aware of [jasmine-let](https://github.com/xaethos/jasmine-let), but it is 4 years old, unmaintained, and doesn't look like a popular or official tool.  Also, I'm relatively new to more modern Javascript development, so I don't even know where `component install _____` comes from (what tool).

This seems to be a useful blog post if I wanted to roll my own solution: http://blog.gypsydave5.com/2015/03/21/lazy-eval-and-memo/

Oh, and in case it matters, I will mention that I am writing in ES6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for lazy variable evaluation in a Jasmine unit test, there are a slim few alternatives, but there is [a fork](https://github.com/globetro/jasmine-let) made last year to let it work with v2.3+ by a fellow named Warren Ouyang (globetro).

There is also [a closed issue](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/971) on the Mocha Github describing the scenario exactly. Some people have posted examples that match the feature, alternatives, and explicit implementations of the feature that are more like RSpec there. (See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-lazy-bdd) and [here](https://github.com/stalniy/bdd-lazy-var).)

```
describe('Thing', () => {
  def('arg', () => null )

  return describe('process', () => {
    def('process', () => new Thing().process($arg) )

    context('given 3', () => {
      def('arg', () => 3 )
      it('returns 12', () => expect($process).to.equal(12))
    })

    context('given 7', () => {
      def('arg', () => 7)
      it('returns 42', () => expect($process).to.equal(42))
    })
  })
})
```

[Here's the above example on jsfiddle.net.](https://jsfiddle.net/empgtL68/9/) This uses a more terse style of JavaScript.

[Here's the previous example of using bdd-lazy-var/rspec on jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/L2okxt72/2/).

*Edit: See other answer using CoffeeScript for brevity. This answer is JavaScript.*

Comment: I actually started rolling my own solution, but thanks, I will look over the links you provided.

Comment: Added an example of using bdd-lazy-var/rspec for you.

Comment: Comes short of rspec's brevity with `let`, but this is good.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh. You want brevity.

Comment: @Pistos There you go, brevity -- err, CoffeeScript, in all it's glory. ☺

Comment: @Pistos I updated this example with a more terse syntax of JavaScript, and used the example you provided as a base.

Comment: TylerY86: Now that's more like it!  Good job.  I appreciate the time you spent over multiple days.  The bounty is yours.

Answer (score 2):

This was a problem I faced, and I wasn’t satisfied with the libraries I found to do the job, so I built my own!

https://github.com/enova/givens

Lazy evaluation with behavior designed to mimic rspec behavior almost exactly (with the concession that I put the variables on an object as getters, to keep everything contained).

You could even name the register function “let” instead of the default “given” to make it even more rspec-like if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you want *brevity*, you might not actually want JavaScript.

```
describe 'Thing', ->
  describe 'process', ->
    def 'arg', -> null
    def 'result', -> new Thing().process($arg)

    context 'given 3', ->
      def 'arg', -> 3
      it 'returns 12', ->
        expect($result).to.equal(12)
    return

    context 'given 7', ->
      def 'arg', -> 7
      it 'returns 42', ->
        expect($result).to.equal(42)
    return
```

[**Here's the link to run the test at jsfiddle.net.**](https://jsfiddle.net/empgtL68/8/)

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/empgtL68/5/) is the other answer rewritten in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), which compiles to JavaScript. It compiles to roughly the same thing. [Here](http://js2.coffee/#coffee/try:%23%20setup%0Aexpect%20%3D%20chai.expect%0Amocha.ui%20%27bdd-lazy-var%2Frspec%27%0Awindow.addEventListener%20%27load%27%2C%20-%3E%20mocha.run()%0A%0A%23%20here%27s%20a%20class%20to%20test%0Aclass%20User%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20(attrs)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20for%20key%20of%20attrs%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20attrs%5Bkey%5D%0A%20%20save%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40isNew%20%3D%20true%0A%0A%23%20here%20is%20the%20tests%0Adescribe%20%27User%27%2C%20-%3E%0A%20%20subject%20-%3E%20new%20User(%24attrs)%0A%20%20describe%20%27when%20is%20active%27%2C%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20def%20%27attrs%27%2C%20-%3E%20%7B%20isActive%3A%20true%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20beforeEach%20-%3E%20%24subject.save()%0A%20%20%20%20it%20%27sets%20isActive%20to%20true%27%2C%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20expect(%24subject.isActive).to.be.true%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20expect(!%24subject.isNew).to.be.false%0A%20%20%20%20describe%20%27when%20changed%20to%20inactive%27%2C%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20%27attrs%27%2C%20-%3E%20%7B%20isActive%3A%20false%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20it%20%27sets%20%22isActive%22%20to%20false%27%2C%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20expect(%24subject.isActive).to.be.false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20expect(!%24subject.isNew).to.be.false%0A%0A)'s the link to the compilation result at [js2coffee](http://js2.coffee).

*Edit: Made it more of a different answer.*

Comment: Thanks for this.  That does look tighter, but I actually dislike Coffeescript in general.  :D  And this particular application is not a Rails app.  I'll see what terseness I can attain by way of ES6, what with arrow functions and what not.

Comment: I'll be interested to see what you come up with. :)

Comment: I copied your example line-for-line from your question and translated it. I'll post the JavaScript version of that.